# How are the ADM201 Certification programs scheduled ? do i have to select the dates or otherwise?

Tags: administration, certification

i have already started self preparation on SF ADM201 , but i am not sure on the schedules of the certification program. Do i need to select the dates or are there dates already scheduled for which i need to apply on. How is this scheduling actually happens ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take this exam when you like, it's available as an online proctored version or in testing centres.

Go to http://certification.salesforce.com/ for more information and follow the "register for exam" link in the top right to find more or to set a date.

Comment: my concern is on the dates ! will i have liberty to choose the exam date that i want ? or it is like pre-scheduled ?

Comment: Log on and see for yourself. If you choose the online proctored then you can choose any date you want, subject to availability. If you choose to go to a centre then they may only be open certain days. But you can logon and go through the process to see the dates available before you finalise a booking.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to log into webaccessor, if you already registered, if not create new credentials from below

https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=publicHome&branding=SALESFORCE

once u logged into the webaccessor, click 
the link register for the new exam -> select administration exam -> Register

there are two ways, we can take exam , onsite proctored or online proctored

onsite proctored means you need to take exam in authorized test center

while doing check out, you can find the schedule available based on test center availability you opted.

If you select online proctored, you should have webcam facility.

Comment: thanks @venkatesh, may i know which 1 is better onsite proctored or online proctored. & May i know if i have liberty to select the exam dates ?

Comment: In my opinion onsite proctored is always better.

Answer (score 0):

As @venkatesh and @Doug had mentioned, you can use onsite proctored and online proctored. 
In both cases you can choose your date and time. If you are choosing a testing centre, then check with them on the availability of slots and the time they work and you can book slots accordingly.

If you have a reliable internet connection with good decent speeds then you can take it up online at your convinience.You would need to install some software to take up the exam. There a few requirements you would need to satisfy. You can take a look at them here http://www.webassessor.com/downloads/

If you have a centre pretty nearby and they work during your convenient time, i would just book a slot with them and take it up.

IF you have the time to set everything up and qualify every requirement, then you choose online proctored